# In which layer should be map/change/format the data?

Tags: java, architecture

Imagine that we have a Java project with three different layers: UI (Swing), Service and DAO. The UI calls the Service, and the Service calls the DAO.

In the UI we have a filter with a Calendar. When the search is run, the selected date (and time) in the calendar is sent as parameter to the service.

The problem is that the time of this date needs to be formatted with the last second of the day (23:59:59), so this formating has to be done.

First question, where do I have to format/change the date and the time. In the UI or in the Service? Because if I change it in the UI, I can reuse the service method for any date and time. But if I change it in the service, I would need a new method in the Service if the current time is needed instead of the last second of the day.

And another thing, is a good idea to name the Service Layer as "Service" if exist this data transformation, or would be better to name as "Action Layer" or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

In our project we also use a layer called 'BF' for BusinessFacade. It's between the DAO-s and the Service endpoints.
(We use the naming convention to end such classes with the BF ending.)

I think that's the "Abstraction Layer" you're looking for.

Most of the time you need to make changes in the BF-s, and not the Service end-points.

Formatting is placed in the UI because our program is I18N enabled, and different countries use different time formatting.

What I like in this architecture is that you can attach different CheckStyle rules for each file ending (...BF, ...Service, ...Dao, ..View) and thus you can enforce a somewhat similar implementation of each.

I.e.: forbiding specific imports, making sure no logic is placed in Service layer, etc.

Comment: Where did you put your BF? Betweeen clint and service or between services and DAO's?

Comment: Between Services (Service-handlers) and Dao-s. Calls go down from end-points like this: InvoicingService (interface with @WebService)-> InvoicingServiceHandler -> InvoicingBF -> InvoicingDao. They can be configured with Spring IoC in a super-easy way. :-)

Comment: What is the role of BF here?

Comment: It's the "Abstraction Layer". :-) It's where we place instances of Dao-s configured with @Autowired. All business-related logic is placed in BF methods, ServiceHandlers contain exception handling mostly. It's a bit verbose architecture; adding new features might require many lines of code or many touched classes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends! As a general advice this kind of formatting goes to clint/application layer however if the formatting is a business requiement of your services then its should go to your service or even business logic layers.
Ask yourself whether formatting should always apply or not. Then chose the solution that makes the service more reusible.